# 「沢庵石」とは、いったいなんですか？

Tags: translation

ネット辞書には出てきませんが、こんなところに読んだ言葉です：

> 掘建小屋は手作りで、屋根に穴だらけの波型トタンと沢庵石をのせたものである。

[日本三文オペラ　１７４頁](http://www.shinchosha.co.jp/book/112802/)（開高健著）

検索すれば、一応[写真のタグ](https://pixta.jp/tags/%E6%B2%A2%E5%BA%B5%E7%9F%B3)として使われているらしい。ですが、写真のどちらへんに含まれているか、よくわかりません。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「沢庵石{たくあんいし}」＝「漬物石{つけものいし}」

意味は同じですが、日常的には「漬物石」の方がよく使われると思います。漬物を作る時に、樽{たる}の上に置いておく石のことを言います。特別な石ではありません。

[image]

従って、「トタン屋根に沢庵石をのせる」とは、下の写真のように、石の重さで屋根を安定させるということになります。

[image]
<sub>(source: [yimg.jp](https://blogs.c.yimg.jp/res/blog-d1-49/sigema57/folder/518139/65/14459665/img_2?1365921721))</sub>

注：この写真は、海外のものです。日本のものはネット上で探せませんでした。上のイラストにあるように、もっと丸い形の石を想像していただければと思います。おおよその雰囲気だけは、この写真でも十分に伝わるかと思い載せてみました。

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don' mind an answer in English.

From [what I was able to find](http://www.c-z.jp/mimiyori_takuanishi.html), `沢庵{たくあん}石｛いし｝`refers to a heavy  stone used in some pickle preparations to press down the barrel's lid which  is apparently named after [Takuan Sōhō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuan_S%C5%8Dh%C5%8D):

> **Takuan**
>
> Japanese radish preserved in rice bran (crisp, tart, deep
> yellow in color). The most popular way to prepare daikon radish,
> legend has it the pickle was named for the resemblance of the heavy
> stone used in pressing, to the gravestone of pickle inventor and
> vegetarian Zen Priest Takuan. But it is also said that the name came
> from "takuwae-zuke" = to preserve.
> [source](http://pickle-girl.blogspot.be/2009/07/pickle-passport-japanese-tsukemono.html)